# XSL Grouping of elements based on attribute value matched with wildcard

Tags: xslt

I would like to transform this xml fragment

```
<Sets>
    <Set id="category.product.typeA.item1"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeB.item2"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeC.item3"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeA.item2"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeA.item3"/>
    <Set id="category.service.typeA.item1"/>
    <Set id="category.service.typeA.item2"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeA.item4"/>
    <Set id="category.product.typeA.item5"/>
</Sets>
```

into the following xml fragment:

```
<Category id="category.product">
    <Group id="category.product.typeA">
        <Set id="category.product.typeA.item1"/>
        <Set id="category.product.typeA.item2"/>
        <Set id="category.product.typeA.item3"/>
        <Set id="category.product.typeA.item4"/>
        <Set id="category.product.typeA.item5"/>        
    </Group>
    <Group id="category.product.typeB"> 
        <Set id="category.product.typeB.item2"/>
    </Group>
    <Group id="category.product.typeC"> 
        <Set id="category.product.typeC.item3"/>
    </Group>
</Category>
<Category id="category.service">
    <Group id="category.service.typeA">
        <Set id="category.service.typeA.item1"/>
        <Set id="category.service.typeA.item2"/>
    </Group>
</Category>
```

Basically, I would like to put elements into separate groups based on an attribute value.

So, elements with attribute values that match:
category.product.typeA.* should be put in one group 
category.product.typeB.* should be put in another group

If the value of the attribute matches category.product.* the group should be put in one category, and if the value of the attribute matches category.service.* it should be put in another category.

I have made efforts with "starts-with" and "for-each-group", but I am not able to put together both the grouping of the elements and the wildcard matching of the attributes and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Sets">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Set" group-by="string-join(tokenize(@id, '\.')[position() lt 3], '.')">
    <Category id="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="string-join(tokenize(@id, '\.')[position() lt 4], '.')">
        <Group id="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </Group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Category>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that stylesheet with Saxon 9.4 to your input I get the wanted result

```
<Category id="category.product">
   <Group id="category.product.typeA">
      <Set id="category.product.typeA.item1"/>
      <Set id="category.product.typeA.item2"/>
      <Set id="category.product.typeA.item3"/>
      <Set id="category.product.typeA.item4"/>
      <Set id="category.product.typeA.item5"/>
   </Group>
   <Group id="category.product.typeB">
      <Set id="category.product.typeB.item2"/>
   </Group>
   <Group id="category.product.typeC">
      <Set id="category.product.typeC.item3"/>
   </Group>
</Category>
<Category id="category.service">
   <Group id="category.service.typeA">
      <Set id="category.service.typeA.item1"/>
      <Set id="category.service.typeA.item2"/>
   </Group>
</Category>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not ever think of "tokenize", but I will sure add tokenize to my "xsl toolbox".